# Getting Windows Service To Read Registry HKLM

Tags: vb.net, service, registry

I've been having a heck of a time trying to get this to work.  I wrote both a service and a form application in VB.NET, both of which need to access a registry key to locate a computer that has my database on it.  In the forms app it works great, but the service does not.  I thought it was a permissions problem so I checked permissions on the server (Windows 2008) and they were fine - I even went as far as to run the service as the admin in case that was the problem but still no joy.  Is there something wrong with my code?

I have tried ways to access the registry.  The first method just sets the server variable to nothing and the second method the 'rk' variable ends up being nothing (telling me that it cannot even locate the sub key):

```
Dim server As String = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\EPS\XPV", "Server", Nothing)
```

and the second one is:

```
Dim rk As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("\SOFTWARE\EPS\XPV")
```

The service itself starts up just fine because I'm getting my log messages right after these lines that tell me the value is blank so it just comes down to figuring out why I cannot access the registry in the service even though I can in the forms app.

Comment: Is the service 32-bit and the forms app 64-bit? or vice versa?

Comment: The service is 32 bit and the platform is 64, but so is my forms app as well

Comment: I'm surprised no movement on this in over a week, I was hoping this was an easy solution but it's not looking like it is.

Answer (score 1):

Either look under HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node for your keys/values, or compile your application as 64bit.